# Advise on ADF layout for email contacts

Tags: user-interface, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a requirement to show email recipients contact in a window. I am confused on what ADF layout is to be used.
Requirement is :
|To: <.input field> <.Contact name1> <.Contact Name2>... |

Contact names can be upto any number. So, if it takes up maximum width, next contact should be in the next line.

As far as i know, PanelGroupLayout can be either horizontal or vertical. So it doesnt help me here.
PanelFormLayout arrranges the contacts vertically first. So i cant use it here.

Is there any other ADF component that can be of help? Or do i need to write code and programatically create components with different layouts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [PanelFormLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_panelFormLayout.html) to layout field and their prompts and try changing the rows to 1 and maxcolumns to however many you have. Or the [PanelGridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26098_01/apirefs.1112/e17491/tagdoc/af_panelGridLayout.html), depending on ADF version, which you don't mention.